# "Qu'il ne l'est"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, usage, comparatifs

I've seen the *qu'il ne l'est/qu'elle ne l'est* being translated as *than it is*
For example in the sentence *Ce problème apparaît plus difficile qu'il ne l'est en réalité.*
I don't understand the *ne l'* part of this phrase

- why there is *ne*?
- what is *l'* referring to?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, the *ne* is a [**ne explétif**](https://bescherelle.ca/le-ne-expletif/) ([here is an explanation in English](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/ne-expletif/) for those who would be more comfortable with it). It can be used in several cases, one of which being the following:

> La phrase principale est une comparaison d’inégalité (construite avec : plus que [...]). « *Leurs cas de conscience, complaisamment exposés, me troublaient moins qu‘ils ne m’édifiaient…* ».
>
> **EN:** The main sentence is an inequality comparison (built with "plus que"). « *Leurs cas de conscience, complaisamment exposés, me troublaient moins qu‘ils ne m’édifiaient…* ».

The *l'* refers to the word ***difficile***.

This sentence means that the problem appears more difficult than it really is.